# how to calculate hours,minutes and seconds from total minutes in php?

Tags: php

I am developing one website in php.

I need to add jobs to the sql server 2008 database.

I am taking job duration in minutes and i want to convert it in to H:i:s format.

I am using this code :

```
  $hours = (int)($duration / 60);
  $minutes = $duration - ($hours * 60);
  $time = $hours.":".$minutes;
```

It works fine with int duration 30,60,100,120 etc.

but if duration is 1.33 or 5.40 than the output should be 00:01:30 or 00:05:40 respectively.

How can i do this ?

Comment: I think you should check to see if the input has a `.` in it, and if so, use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Comment: check my answer, it will help you

Comment: @Mausami Check my answer, it will give you the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<?php
 $duration = "1.33";
 $hours    = (int)($duration / 60);
 $minutes  = $duration - ($hours * 60);   

  date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
  $date = new DateTime($hours.":".$minutes);
  echo $date->format('H:i:s');
?>
```

output

```
00:01:33
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. ❤

Answer (score 2):

Use the DateInterval class if you're running PHP > 5.3.0:

```
$interval = new DateInterval('100 minutes');
$interval->format('%H:%I:%S');  // prep for MySQL database.
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are taking minutes, this code is working perfectly

```
$valueInMinutes = 135;

echo intval($valueInMinutes / 60);
echo " h ";
echo intval($valueInMinutes % 60);
```

and will output

```
2 h 15
```

If you have to manage the days, just change a little bit the code to:

```
$value = 1505;

echo intval($value / 1440);
echo " day(s) ";
echo intval(($value % 1440) / 60);
echo " h ";
echo intval($value % 60);
```

will output

```
1 day(s) 1 h 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with php `date` function :

```
$hours = (int)($duration / 60);
$minutes = $duration - ($hours * 60);
$time = date("H:i:s", strtotime($hours.":".$minutes));
echo $time;
```

More info on `date` can be found here http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks sabari. but i want to covert total minutes in hours,minutes and seconds. means if total minutes is 5.40 than it should be display as 00:05:40

Comment: @Mausami This will work exactly the way you want. What is the output you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$time = 5.40;
$newtime = floatval($time);
echo number_format($newtime,2,':',null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo $time = date("H:i:s", strtotime($hours)) . ":" . date("H:i:s", strtotime($minutes));
```

**Output**

```
01:33:00 : 05:40:00
```

Comment: Thanks sumit for your help. but i want minutes in H:i:s format not hours so if minutes is 1.33 or 5.40 than it should give output as 00:01:33 or 00:05:40

Comment: @Mausami for that you need to put leading `0` in time like `0.1.33` . **ex.** `echo $time = date("H:i:s", strtotime("0.".$hours)) . ":" . date("H:i:s", strtotime("0.".$minutes));`